# Docker run Cron in a container with other service using proxy

Tags: docker, proxy

I have a django application in a docker container. I built the image using the

```
docker build --build-arg http_proxy=$http_proxy \
             --build-arg https_proxy=$https_proxy \
             --build-arg no_proxy=$no_proxy \
             -t <tag> .
```

And I have my proxy variables set in my current terminal session using

```
export http_proxy=http://user:pass@proxy.company.com:8099/
export https_proxy=http://user:pass@proxy.company.com:8099/
export no_proxy=*.local,localhost,169.254.169.254,*.abc.company.com,*.cloud.company.com
```

Below is the Dockerifle:

```
FROM artifactory.cloud.company.com/amazonlinux:2.0.20181010

ENV PIP_INDEX_URL https://artifactory.cloud.company.com/artifactory/api/pypi/pypi-internalfacing/simple/


RUN yum install -y python3 python3-devel python3-setuptools python3-pip git gcc
RUN pip3 install --upgrade --trusted-host artifactory.cloud.company.com pip setuptools
RUN amazon-linux-extras install nginx1.12
RUN yum install -y python2-pip
RUN pip2 install supervisor -i https://artifactory.cloud.company.com/artifactory/api/pypi/pypi-internalfacing/simple/ --trusted-host artifactory.cloud.company.com
RUN pip3 install uwsgi
RUN pip3 install django requests python-decouple
RUN mkdir -p /ASVDASHBOARD
# Application folder on the server with absolute path.
ADD ./ASVDASHBOARD /ASVDASHBOARD

WORKDIR /ASVDASHBOARD
RUN mkdir -p /etc/supervisor/
RUN cp ASVDASHBOARD_nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
RUN cp ASVDASHBOARD_supervisor.conf /etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf
#RUN cp ASVDASHBOARD_supervisor.conf /etc/supervisord.d/
RUN chown -R nginx:nginx /ASVDASHBOARD && \
    mkdir -p /ASVDASHBOARD/logs/ && \
    touch /ASVDASHBOARD/logs/dashboard.log
RUN python3 manage.py makemigrations && \
    python3 manage.py migrate --run-syncdb && \
    python3 manage.py migrate

RUN python3 manage.py update_data
RUN mkdir /run/uwsgi && chmod -R 777 /run/uwsgi
EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["supervisord", "-c", "/etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf"]
```

I also run the container using

```
docker run -it -d --name final_dashboardd -e http_proxy -e https_proxy -e no_proxy -p 8080:8080 py37:v3
```

Now, I want to run a cron job in the container to run this command `python3 /pathtofile/manage.py update_data`. To just run manually, I will have to attach a shell terminal to the container using exec, set the proxy and then run the command, it works fine.

How do I set/pass proxy to run this cron job now.
I tried

```
 */1 * * * * python3 /pathtofile/manage.py update_data
```

Which didnt work. How to pass proxy here, Since I am attached to a terminal and have my proxy variables setup. it works But how to setup proxy for cron.